# why is pre_get_posts not working

Tags: query-posts, pre-get-posts

```
 function include_category( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '3' );
}
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'include_category' );
```

I put this piece of code in my index.php which controls the main page.
I want to only show category 3 on the main page. I was using query_post until I realize that is not the most efficient way of doing things.

The code should work but it doesn't.
Any ideas or suggestions will be nice. thanks.

Or if there is a way to do so with wp_query. What would the snippet of code for this function be? I been on this for hours on end. I could not get this to work.

Comment: What happens when you put this in functions.php?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Is it still showing all categories? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/126376/21376

Comment: I got this solved....I put this in functions.php as the code needs to be run before the index.php runs. thanks for the pointer. thank you for your help

Comment: Glad you got it working, might be worthwhile to answer your question and accept it so future visitors can see that you were able to resolve the issue and how to fix it.